# Robots.TXT Disallow Syntax

Tags: robots.txt

I have dynamically created pages, which can have any name.

```
www.example.com/pages/ 
www.example.com/pages/dynamicpage1/ 
www.example.com/pages/dynamicpage2/
```

I want the first url to pages to be crawled, but not any of the dynamic pages

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /pages/*
```

The above will block all three pages listed. How do I just block all the dynamic pages, but not the first url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out..

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /pages/*/
```

Happens all the time, solve the problem seconds after you post it.